# Counter keeps getting reset back to 0

Tags: c#, buffer

I am trying to create my own [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) in C#. I am using a counter to keep track of where I need to insert the next item. Here is a [Link](http://pastebin.com/SpFJFxMc) to the full code and here is the (simplified) code to do so:

```
public class CircularBuffer<T>
{
    private bool _isFull = false;

    private int _size;
    private int _current = 0;

    private BufferItem<T>[] _buffer;

    public CircularBuffer(int size)
    {
        _size = size;
        _buffer = new BufferItem<T>[size];
    }

    public void Insert(T value)
    {
        BufferItem<T> item = new BufferItem<T>(value);
        //Removed code to check if the buffer is full, if so over-write the oldest item
        //and don't insert at the current position
        _buffer[_current] = item;
        _isFull = (_current == (_size - 1));
        _current++;

        //Age all items            
    }
```

It all works fine and dandy until after I increment the current position and try to add another item:

[image]

Here I added the item `"first"` and the current position (`_current`) is incremented.

[image]

I added the item `"third"` but the current position gets reset to 0. There is absolutely no other code including `_current` other than declaring it, accessing it and incrementing it.
What in the world is going on? Here is the code for `BufferItem<T>`:

```
public class BufferItem<T>
{
    public int Age = 0;
    public T Item;

    public BufferItem(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full implementation? It's difficult to see what might be happening without the full context in which this code is running.

Comment: Are you re-instantiating your CircularBuffer object somewhere in this process? That would reset `_current` to 0.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I have edited the post. The link is at the top.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher I will have a look.

Comment: I have compiled your code without issue. `_current` is incrementing as expected...

Comment: It turns out that there was a method that kept on resetting the `CircularBuffer` object everytime I called it. Silly me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class methods are fine. Your `_current` variable works fine, too. The issue lies outside of the `CircularBuffer` class. Somewhere where this is being implemented, the CircularBuffer object in question is getting reset in some way.